# Help for solving a partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have to solve the following partial differential equation,

$$y \frac{dF}{dx} + x \Bigg[1−(x2−y2)\bigg(\frac{2c_0}{x^4} y \sqrt{x^2−y^2} +f(x) y^2+2g(x)\bigg)\Bigg]\frac{dF}{dy}=0$$
where $F(x,y)$ is a differentiable function of two-variables and $f(x)$, $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are differentiable functions of one variable $x$ where $y\neq 0$ and $x^2−y^2>0$ and $c_0\in R$.

.

**My Attempt:**
Its characteristic equation is as the following

$$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{\frac{x}{y}\bigg[1−(x2−y2)\bigg(\frac{2c_0}{x^4} y \sqrt{x^2−y^2} +f(x) y^2+2g(x)\bigg)\bigg]},$$
then we have
$$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{x}{y}\bigg[1−(x^2−y^2)\bigg(\frac{2c_0}{x^4} y \sqrt{x^2−y^2} +f(x) y^2+2g(x)\bigg)\bigg].$$

We know
$$\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{x^2 - y^2}}{y}\bigg) = \frac{x}{y \sqrt{x^2 - y^2}} -\frac{x^2}{y^2 \sqrt{x^2 - y^2}}\frac{dy}{dx}.$$

By putting $\theta:= \frac{\sqrt{x^2 - y^2}}{y}$,  we get

$$\theta ' = \bigg(2xg - \frac{1}{x}\bigg) \theta^3 +\frac{2c_0}{x}\theta^2 + \bigg(2xg -\frac{1}{x} + x^3 f\bigg)\theta,$$
where a first order ordinary differential equation of third degree where I don't know how to solve it.
Is my solution correct?  Is there another substitution that might work better?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: With two different unknown functions $f$ and $g$, it's very unlikely this has anything closed-form.

Comment: It might help to know the context of how this equation came up.